# Using Oracle's DRCP (Database Pool) with the JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, connection-pooling

I'm trying to utilize the new DRCP feature in Oracle 11g.
We have a multi OS product and are already using the JDCB driver to connect our java applications to the database.

The goal is to setup a common database pool for all applications; Web Serivces, GUI's and engines. This in order for us to control the load on the database.

I can read that the 11g JDBC driver does not support the DRCP feature - A little weird - but that the 12c driver does.
Is it possible to use this driver together with the 11g database and a JDBC based driver?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.  This is not the way to accomplish what you have in mind.  Sounds like the perfect way to cripple all your services, interfaces, and engines.  Match the driver to your database and JVM.  Better to restrict access to databases through services only.  That's how Amazon does it.

Comment: It seems a little crazy to call a service to access a database that is just setting in the adjacent rack...

Comment: I was in fact thinking of setting up a DRCP pool for engines, one for the web services and a third for the GUI.

Comment: GUIs shouldn't need direct access to a database.  I still would not recommend sharing pools.  They ought to be independent.  There's no advantage to doing it your way that I can see.  I'd drop that idea.

Comment: I agree that the GUI shouldn't access the DB directly, but this is where we are now. Any pointers on how to do this are more than welcome :-)

Comment: I'll say it again: Don't share connection pools.  Give each user their own.